# Find Orthogonal Vector's Peak Point

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, cross-product

I am given a 3-component vector $\vec v$. There are obviously an infinite number of orthogonal vectors to $\vec v$. I need to find the specific orthogonal vector, lets call it $\vec{x}$, in the plane defined by $\vec v$ and the positive z-unit vector.

Is there some sort of standardized equation to find $\vec x$?
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a _unit_ vector (or a vector of fixed length), perhaps...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I really don't care about the length of $\vec x$ cause I can scale it however I want. I just can't figure out how to find the positive vector in that plane.

Comment: I ask because "most positive $z$-component (in the plane spanned by $v$ and $e_{3} = (0, 0, 1)$)" makes no sense (as Emilio Novati's answer notes) without some constraint (on length, for instance), but the question asks for "the" vector $x$ as if there's a unique choice.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I get what you're saying now. I've edited, yeah, when asking for, "The most positive z-component," in my mind I was comparing orthogonal *unit* vectors. I can see how that didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality (i.e., up to overall scaling), you're looking for a vector of the form
$$
x = cv + e_{3} = cv + (0, 0, 1)
$$
orthogonal to $v$ for some (unknown) scalar $c$. Taking the dot product with $v$ gives $0 = c(v \cdot v) + v \cdot e_{3}$, or
$$
c = -\frac{v \cdot e_{3}}{v \cdot v}.
$$
(This presumes $v \neq 0$, but if $v = 0$ the vector $x = e_{3}$ suits your needs.)

Comment: I'd like to accept this, for it to be a complete answer could you define $e_3$ so future readers don't need to go dig through comments to find out what it is?

Comment: The definition of $e_{3}$ is in the first displayed equation...? :)

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$ all the vectors $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)^T$ orthogonal to $v$ are on the plane:
$$\vec x \cdot \vec v=(x,y,z)\cdot(v_1,v_2,v_3)^T=0$$
so there are vectors orthogonal to $\vec v$ vith any component $x$ , $y$ or $z$ as great as we want.

---

The plane containing $\vec k = (0,0,1)^T$ and $\vec v$ has equation: $\vec x \cdot(\vec k \times \vec v)=0$ i.e. $v_2x-v_1y=0$. intersect this plane with the plane orthogonal to $\vec v$ (i.e. $ v_1x+v_2y+v_3z=0$) and you find all vectors orthogonals to $\vec v$ and in the plane containing $\vec k$ and $\vec v$.

Comment: Your answer helps me find *an* orthogonal vector but I don't see how it specifically helps me find *the* orthogonal vector. I've added some more explanation to hopefully clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: I've added something to my answer. I hope it can solve your clarified question.

Comment: I agree that $\vec x \cdot (\vec k \times \vec v) = 0$, but I can't get from there to: $v_2x - v_1y = 0$ Can you help me with the jump?

Comment: Do you agree that $\vec k \times \vec v=v_2 \vec i -v_1 \vec j$?

Comment: Because $k_3$ is positive, I think it's actually $\vec k \times \vec v = -v_2\vec i + v_1\vec j$ Either way, I'm having trouble seeing how this solves for $\vec x$.